# Archer Minimum Attempt Probability Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, negative-binomial

An archer is shooting at a target with a probability of $0.4$ 
Find the minimum amount of attempts so the chances to hit the target $80$ times are $0.9$.

I think this can be solved with negative binomal distribution but I'm not sure how. Please help!

What I got so far:

$x:$ the number of experiments
$x\: \tilde{}\: NB(80, 0.4)$

$p(x \ge 80) = 0.9$.

Comment: That is not quite right: the negative binomial is the number of successes before a certain number of failures, not the number of *attempts* before a certain number of failures. But the two are related in a simple way, since the number of attempts is the number of successes plus the number of failures. But you can also just use the binomial: you are asking "what is the smallest $n$ such that $P(Bin(n,0.4) \geq 80) \geq 0.9$?" You can get an approximate answer by normal approximation and then check it with more exact calculation.

Comment: It is I think more straightforward to use the binomial, and for computation the normal approximation to the binomial.

Comment: What would the solution look like? I need to have a sum(i = 1, to 80) with the $Bin$ equation? (if we consider the opposite event??)

Comment: Proceeding that way, you want to find $n$ such that $\sum_{k=0}^{80} {n \choose k} 0.4^k 0.6^{n-k} < 0.1$. I don't think there is a way to solve this inequality with pure algebra.

Answer (score 0):

It is $P(X\geq 80)=1-P(X\leq 79)$, where $X \sim Bin(n,0.4)$. The equation is

$1-P(X\leq 79)\geq 0.9 \quad |-1$

$-P(X\leq 79)\geq -0.1 \quad |\cdot (-1)$

$P(X\leq 79)\leq 0.1 $

Using De Moivre-Laplace it looks like

$\Phi\left( \frac{79+0.5-n\cdot 0.4}{\sqrt{n\cdot 0.4 \cdot 0.6}} \right)\leq 0.1$

$\Phi(z)$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution. +0.5 is the continuity correction factor.

$\frac{79+0.5-n\cdot 0.4}{\sqrt{n\cdot 0.4 \cdot 0.6}} \leq \Phi^{-1}\left(0.1\right)$

$\frac{79+0.5-n\cdot 0.4}{\sqrt{n\cdot 0.4 \cdot 0.6}} \leq -1.29$

Now you can solve the (in-)equality for n.

Check the result for n and the check by using the binomial distribution:

[Link 1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=79%2B0.5-0.4*n%3C-1.29*sqrt%280.24*n%29)

[Link 2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-sum_%28k%3D0%29%5E79%20%28223%20choose%20k%20%29*0.4%5Ek*0.6%5E%28223-k%29)